# Android Project Import to Eclipse does not show Project name in Import Projects window but rather 'PTPlayer' - the project is not importing correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, import, project, buildbox

I have created a game in Buildbox which I've exported to Android. Upon importing this project to Eclipse (Import -> Existing Android Code into Workspace -> Browse for folder) the project does not appear, but rather the directory under 'Project to Import', and 'PTPlayer' under 'New Project Name' ([as per this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZyvn.png)) which indicates it hasn't imported correctly.

I am aware that I should get two items, one with the 'New Project Name' (something in the format of com.companyname.gamename) as well as a lib item.

Annoyingly I was able to produce the desired output about eighteen months ago using the same procedure, and I have followed various tutorials online without success. Clearly I am doing something wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `General -> Existing Projects` into Workspace instead of the Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace.

[image]

and go to correct location：
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I tried that but the project is still appearing as a 'PTPlayer' project - I have no idea what this is.